# Python How can I find straight lines in numpy array intersecting a curved path?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, edge-detection, hough-transform

I calculated the vertical gradient of a numpy array, and isolated the edges. This allowed me to calculate red curves from interpolation.

I have now the edges from the horizontal gradient: a numpy array filled with 0 (green), 1 (yellow) and -1 (blue).

Which is the best way to find the long straight lines intersecting the red paths?

Straight lines are not orthogonal to the red path.

[image: ight]

Comment: [HoughLines](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga46b4e588934f6c8dfd509cc6e0e4545a) or HoughLinesP first for the yellow and then for the blue lines?

Comment: Tried `probabilistic_hough_line` , but the combination of parameters does not allow to control the angles. it finds, both on the image and its transpose, mainly small lines connecting several yellow points but horizontally.

Comment: Hough is total overkill here, don't use that.

Comment: Are these post barcodes ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust no, they are sky emission lines detected in an échelle spectrum

Answer (score 1):

It is no big deal to trace the yellow or blue line segments by going from pixel to pixel. On every pixel traversed, you can check if you are above or below a red line, and when there is a change, you have found an intersection. At the same time, you can measure the segment lengths.